# Symfony 5 - Regex Validator which was working now doesn't work

Tags: regex, validation, symfony5

So i have an Entity with @Assert/Regex

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=30, nullable=false, options={"comment"="input#text&[A-Za-z \-\'àâäçéèêëîïôöùûüÿæœÀÂÄÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖÙÛÜŸÆŒ]{2,30}@Prénom"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank (
     *     message="Le champs [prénom] ne peut être vide",
     *     groups={"registration"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Regex (
     *     pattern="/^[A-Za-z \-\'àâäçéèêëîïôöùûüÿæœÀÂÄÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖÙÛÜŸÆŒ]{2,30}$/",
     *     message="Champs prénom : La saisie est invalide (min: 2, max: 30)")
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=30, nullable=false, options={"comment"="input#text&[A-Za-z \-\'àâäçéèêëîïôöùûüÿæœÀÂÄÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖÙÛÜŸÆŒ]{2,30}@Nom"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank (
     *     message="Le champs [nom] ne peut être vide",
     *     groups={"registration"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Regex (
     *     pattern="/^[A-Za-z \-\'àâäçéèêëîïôöùûüÿæœÀÂÄÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖÙÛÜŸÆŒ]{2,30}$/",
     *     message="Champs nom : La saisie est invalide (min: 2, max: 30)")
     */
    private $lastname;
```

And i have my controller like so (I purposely removed most of my code to keep it lisible)

```
public function register(ValidatorInterface $validator, EntityManagerInterface $emi): Response
{
    $newUsers = new Users();
            
    // Setting the values
    $newUsers
        ->setFirstname($request->get('firstname'))
        ->setLastname($request->get('lastname'));

    $errorsUsers = $validator->validate($newUsers, null, ['registration']);
    foreach ($errorsUsers as $v){
        $msgErrors .= "\n- " . $v->getMessage() . ".";
    }
}
```

Before everything worked perfectly. And now the Assert\NotBlank is still working but the Assert\Regex is not. It's like, it doesn't even compare it.

I tried :

- php bin/console debug:validator 'App\Entity\Users' (all seems fine)
- composer dump-autoload (nothing change)
- Put instead in my regex simple parttern like "/\d/" (even that when i type 'Toto' it doesn't trigger and return a violation)

I don't know why it's not working anymore and thats why i hate symfony for this cause it doesn't even give an error or message to start with.

If someone has encountered this problem and has a solution to give, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was the fact that i didn't put the groups in the regex too.

so for each Assert that you add on a var, you need to specify the groups.

I didn't think of it, because in the doc it says that if you don't specify groups it means that it apply for everything. Obviously it is not.

Thanks doc.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not fully correct. If you don't specify groups it means that it apply for everything, which it is TRUE! BUT, you have to pass the "Default" (it really is the name of symfony default validation group). Otherwise, if you only use your custom validation group, and leave the "Default" out of it, then it will ignore the asserts with no custom validation group specified.